# Session Attribute gets cleared when application is published with Apache

Tags: java, apache, session, jboss

I have a registry that keeps track of certain operations made during the user session. It's basically a wrapper for a list and it is stored as a session attribute in a servlet

```
class Registry {
    private List<Operation> ops = new ArrayList<Operation>();

    public Registry add(Operation o) {
        this.ops.add(o);
        return this;
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Registry reg = (Registry)request.getSession().getAttribute("registry");

    if (reg == null) {
        reg = new Registry();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("registry", reg);
    }

    System.out.println("reg " + reg);
    reg.add(new Operation("info"));
}
```

When I run my web app via JBoss, I always get the same object and with every get request, the registry keeps growing. In the above example, if you make 10 get requests, you'll end up with a registry with 10 Operations.

But when JBoss is used in combination with apache, the registry is cleared out in every get request and a new Registry instance is created every time, so you always end up with an empty registry.

I know this must be a very simple situation for people who knows about servers, but my knowledge in that area is infinitesimal.

So I'll thank you if you could provide information about how to keep the registry working or what can be causing this.

Comment: It might have something to do with the way JBoss manages the sessions, have a look at [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/152616?_sscc=t).

Comment: @DarshanMehta thanks

Comment: did it solve the problem?

Comment: @DarshanMehta Nope. JBoss does not seem to be causing the problem, it seems it is an Apache thing. There's something called "reverse proxy" that could be causing the issue.